# Is there a shorcut for 'Next' and 'Previous' after incremental search in Notepad++?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++

I'm trying to learn to use only the keyboard with some applications, one of them Notepad++.

When I do an incremental search (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>), I have to go back to the mouse to go to next/previous matches. I cannot find any shorcut. Is there one already or a way to add one?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When the cursor (|) is inside the *Find* dialog:

<kbd>Enter</kbd>: Find next

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>: Find previous

---

Or `Quick Incremental Search`:

**Select and Find Next**: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>

Then

<kbd>F3</kbd>: Find next

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>: Find previous

Comment: Note, that since 7.3.3 you can press SHIFT+ENTER even when the find dialog is closed, yey :-)

Comment: This did not work when I tried it on Notepad++ version 6.3 (2013-02-03).